# changing Message for ProgressDialog android

Tags: android, dialog

I have an `ProgressDialog` where in shows while sending mail. The progress dialog works across activities and classes as one of the blog had given an hint showing `ProgressDialog` across activities.

Below is the code as I am overriding `onCreateDialog()`

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    if(id == ID_SENDING_MAIL){
    ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loadingDialog.setMessage("Sending Email...");
    loadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(true);
    return loadingDialog;
}

return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

then I call the mail sending as below

```
showDialog(ID_SENDING_MAIL);
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){//I am calling Mail Send here 

        dismissDialog(Email.ID_SENDING_MAIL);
    }
}).start();
```

In run method I instantiate mail class and send host of parameters.
This is working fully but I want to set different messages to ProgressDialog.
Like at the time of connecting to Host

```
 Sending Mail then
 Mail Sent Successfully
```

How could we carry out those changes when used with `onCreateDialog()`.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to do this by using `AsyncTask`:

and in `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` use progress param to set desired messages to `ProgressDialog`(using swith of any other method to determine wat the exact message should be)

Comment: thanks. I am using Mail class like  `MailUtil branchEmail = new MailUti("username", "password"); `
then I add properties like `branchMail.setSubject`, message, could you let me know how can I call AsyncTask for the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display different messages on different stages in network thread, then use `AysncTask`, and after each step in `doInBackground()` method, invoke `publishProgress` method. 
in `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` method change message in progress dialog.

Comment: thanks. I am using Mail class like  `MailUtil branchEmail = new MailUti("username", "password"); `
then I add properties to the 'branchMail.setSubject`, message, could you let me know how can I call AsyncTask for the above.